# I want to add a "like" functionality to my site, but will i get into hot water with Facebook?

Tags: intellectual-property

I have a site that would I would like to add some "like" functionality to. After lots of digging I couldn't find any evidence to suggest that I would get into any bother with Facebook if I did.

Does anyone happen to know if this is ok to do? There are literally hundreds of sites with star ratings, hearts and who knows what else. But nobody seems to be doing the "like" except Facebook.

Comment: It's also an option for IP.Board.

Comment: You should make sure that your like button looks distinct from facebook's.